# Chrome: Site has updated in the background

Tags: google-chrome, push

I keep getting these notifications despite not having an RT tab open. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websites in Chrome will ask you for permission before they display notifications. If you grant that permission, the site can send notifications even if no related tabs are open.

To revoke the permissions for RT.com:

- On your computer, open Chrome
- Go to rt.com
- To the left of the web address, click the icon you see. (It will likely be a lock or information icon)
- Click Site settings.
- Change the Notifications setting. Your changes will automatically save.

Instructions taken from [Chrome's support pages](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: +1 You got there first.

Comment: ahh easy, I thought there may have been bidirectional communication

Comment: But that seems to disable notifications even if the tab is open. Isn't there a golden middle "receive notifications if tab is open, but not otherwise"?

Comment: There is not. Notifications are intended as a way for sites to communicate with you regardless if its tabs are open, so there's no check for if one exists or not.

Comment: Doesn't this just hide the notification. It doesn't actually stop the site from updating in the background. How do I stop that?

Comment: @phocks Disable background sync (see answer).

Answer (score 5):

Disabling the notification is like breaking the thermometer.
The actual right that seems to cause this is "Background synchronization".

Chrome settings -> Privacy and security -> Site Settings -> Permissions -> Background Sync

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but the notification keeps appearing: do I need to restart Chrome to enable it?